# What would be the correct approach to reinject dependencies after deserialization?

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization

I'm using dependency injection without any framework, pure POJOs.

Say I have a Person Class which depends on a JsonHelper class , how would I reinject the JsonHelper class back to the Person class after deserializing it from a JSON?

Example:

```
public class Person extends Entity
{
    private transient JsonHelper jsonHelper;
    private String name;

    public Person (JsonHelper jsonHelper, String name)
    {
        this.jsonHelper= jsonHelper;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getJson()
    {
        return this.jsonHelper.toJson(this.name);
    }
}
```

Note that I have the JsonHelper instance after deserializing in my runtime, not in my JSON.

Should I have a builder for building the Person from a JSON?

Comment: You shouldn’t be serialising objects that have such things - you should only serialise DTOs etc. Consider changing your design such that something logs a Person rather than Person logs itself.

Comment: Furthermore, loggers are almost always `static`.

Comment: I've updated my question to show you better what I need.
The Entity class needs specific a specific JSON from each of the implementors, so I can't pass the Person class to a static JSON method, since it would not know what JSON to produce.
It means that I have 2 different JSONs here, one of the supposed DTO (Person class itself), and another one for a total different use, the `getJson()` method.
@Bohemian

Comment: Bohemian's insight still applies. Consider changing your design such that something converts a Person to JSON rather than a Person converting itself.